# How do you add hyperlinks to Leaflet polylines created via Leaflet.Draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using Leaflet.Draw, and I want to allow the lines that I draw to have hyperlinks in them so that someone can click on the link and open a new page.

How do I add a link to a polyline created via Leaflet.Draw? When I addLayer to drawnItems, how  can I give that layer another attribute that could be a URL?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems
        }
    });
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

Comment: This was cross-posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140909/how-do-you-add-hyperlinks-to-leaflet-polylines-created-via-leaflet-draw-crossp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will open a new page when the drawn feature is clicked:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    layer.on('click', function(){
       window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank');
    });  

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

This will bind a popup with a url:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    layer.bindPopup('<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>');

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

But not sure what you are after here exactly; you may want to add more information to the question. In general, the 'draw:created' callback is the place where you would add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks @toms! That makes perfect sense. I'll want to let users of this map add the link in themselves after they place the polyline, but I should be able to figure that out myself probably using layer.bindPopup.